# Remove Character in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Please suggest me how to achieve this in postgresql

```
select replace (INITCAP((encode(decode((
CONCAT_WS('',REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (INITCAP ('Györgyi'), CHR (13), CHR (13)),CHR (10),CHR (10)), CHR (9),CHR (9))
,REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (INITCAP ('GÃ©gÃ©ny'), CHR (13),CHR (13)),CHR (10),CHR (10)), CHR (9),CHR (9))
)),'escape'),'escape'))) , CHR (10), CHR (10)) AS Name;
```

Current Output - `Gy\303\266rgyig\303\243\302\251g\303\243\302\251ny`

Expected Output - `Gyorgyi Gacgacny`

Comment: What exactly is the point? I don't feel motivated to look into this without a good cause. Is this from some sort of "obfuscated SQL context"?

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe , actually I need to convert form Oracle.
select REPLACE (INITCAP(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort((REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (INITCAP ('Györgyi'), CHR (13)),CHR (10)), CHR (9))||' '|| REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (INITCAP ('GÃ©gÃ©ny'), CHR (13)),CHR (10)), CHR (9)) ), 'nls_sort=binary_ai')))) , CHR (0)) AS MemberAccountName from dual;

Comment: Rather than slavishly translating this - er - interesting code, take a step back and figure out the purpose of that piece of code. Then your job will be easier.